# How to break this while loop?

Tags: python

```
def left():
    print("left")
def right():
    print("right")
def main():
    command = input ("Enter your command: ")
    if command == "left":
        left()
    if command == "right":
        right()
    if command ==  "done":
        break
while True:
    main()
```

I don't understand how to break out of this while loop while calling the main function.I am trying to break out of the while loop while calling the function main().

Comment: You can't: you have to call `break` directly somewhere in that while loop, not indirectly inside a function.

Comment: Put the while loop in the main function.

Comment: You can have `main` return a value, and depending on that value, you have have  `if main() == <some-value>: break` line inside your while loop. `True` for continuing and `False` for stopping could be a simple starter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The break on the function does not have effect on your while loop, try returning `True` and checking the return value on each iteration:

```py
def main():
    command = input ("Enter your command: ")
    if command == "left":
        left()
    elif command == "right":
        right()
    elif command ==  "done":
        return True
while True:
    if main():
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer from Pedro Maia is the best one, but you can also call `exit()` if you are sure that you will end your process and will not leak memory in any way.

```
def main():
    command = input ("Enter your command: ")
    if command == "left":
        left()
    elif command == "right":
        right()
    elif command ==  "done":
        exit()

while True:
    main():
```